# Understanding PHP Functions

Tags: php, function, variables

I am beginner in programmer, can anyone describe to me how php function work?
I have searched any tutorial but I am still confusing..

Why this function doesn't work?

```
<?php
$name = "Maria";
$gender = "Female";
$country = "Thailand";

function profile(){
   echo $name . "<br>";
   echo $gender . "<br>";
   echo $country . "<br>";
}
profile()
?>
```

Or like this:

```
<?php
function data(){
   $name = "Maria";
   $gender = "Female";
   $country = "Thailand";
}
function profile(){
   echo $name . "<br>";
   echo $gender . "<br>";
   echo $country . "<br>";
}
data();
profile()
?>
```

Or like this:

```
<?php
function data(){
   $name = "Maria";
   $gender = "Female";
   $country = "Thailand";
}
function profile(){
   data();
   echo $name . "<br>";
   echo $gender . "<br>";
   echo $country . "<br>";
}
profile()
?>
```

How to include variables in php function?
Thanks for help sir...

Comment: `function profile(){
data();
echo $name . "<br>";
echo $gender . "<br>";
echo $country . "<br>";
}
profile()` like in this function profile(); is calling a function, when ever you will call the function, the code inside the `{}` will be executed. Thanks

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: Please read [PHP Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php). SO is not a tutorial site.

Comment: Why this question is downgraded two times? Is stack overflow not the right place for asking this kind of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading tutorials on the subject if you are interested in programming and want to learn more about how to code. Just [search](https://www.google.com.cy/search?q=php+functions+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gws_rd=cr&ei=Ees4VNP9CIL-aMmZgZgE) on how they work, how to pass/return parameters and once you feel comfortable enough using them keep moving on more advanced features.

In your example you are trying to access the `private` variables `$name`, `$gender` and `$country` which are only accessible inside that function's scope.

To access the `global` variables you need to either pass them as parameters to the function:

```
function profile($name,$gender,$country) {
    echo $name . "<br>";
    echo $gender . "<br>";
    echo $country . "<br>";
}
```

or use the `global` keyword inside the function:

```
function profile(){
    global $name,$gender,$country;
    echo $name . "<br>";
    echo $gender . "<br>";
    echo $country . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I need to include some variables in a function, so I think what I need is use "global" keyword... thanks for help sir...

Comment: @IrumCantik This is a typical case where the chosen answer might not be the right answer in the longterm

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. You need to give each variable as a parameter

```
<?php
$name = "Maria";
$gender = "Female";
$country = "Thailand";

function profile($name, $gender, $country){
echo $name . "<br>";
echo $gender . "<br>";
echo $country . "<br>";
}
echo profile($name, $gender, $county);
?>
```

You could also declare a variable in the function itself.

```
<?php
function profile() {
$name = "Maria";
$gender = "Female";
$country = "Thailand";

echo $name . "<br>";
echo $gender . "<br>";
echo $country . "<br>";
}
?>
```

The down side of this is that the variables are hardcoded and can not be changed like the above function.

If you want you want to call a hole lot of variables you could use an array.

```
$data = array('name' => 'Test', 'age' => 18, 'email' => 'test@test.com');

function profile($data) {
    foreach($data as $field => $value) {
       echo 'Field: '.$field.' has a value of: '.$value.'<br>';
    }
}

echo profile($data);
// This should return:
// Field: name has a value of Test
// Field: age has a value of 18
// Field: email has a value of test@test.com
```

You could also follow the following links:

- http://www.codecademy.com/ (take the php course);
- https://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy (watch some tutorials)
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php (arrays)

Comment: Then you should probably rethink what you're trying to do, pass the variables in an array, or make a class for them.

Answer (score 1):

It 's all about the scope of variables in php. Just have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php.

For example

```
$var = 'foo';

// not so good example
function bar() {
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}
bar(); // echos 'foo';

// better example
function bla($parameter) {
    echo $parameter;
}
bla( $var ); // echos 'foo';
```

You have to understand the scope of php.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that the `$name`, `$gender` and `$country` variables have global scope. Within a function, you can't access global variables, unless you explicitly declare them:

```
<?php
$name = "Maria";
$gender = "Female";
$country = "Thailand";

function profile(){
    global $name, $gender, $country;
    echo $name . "<br>";
    echo $gender . "<br>";
    echo $country . "<br>";
}
profile()
?>
```

Having said that, global variables are usually not a clean way to do stuff, and should be avoided. Passing the variables as parameters to your functions would be better:

```
<?php
$name = "Maria";
$gender = "Female";
$country = "Thailand";

function profile($name, $gender, $country) {
    echo $name . "<br>";
    echo $gender . "<br>";
    echo $country . "<br>";
}
profile($name, $gender, $country)
?>
```

This way, the `$name`, `$gender` and `$country` variables are made local to the function.

There's a lot more to scoping of variables than I can describe here, but you can read about it [in the php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)